# Determinar si una fecha ingresada es mayor a la de hoy

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, javascript-objeto

Estoy intentando determinar si una fecha que ingreso es mayor a la fecha de hoy en día.
El problema que tengo es que si ingreso meses o días sin doble digito aunque la fecha se mayor a la de hoy no la toma como tal.

Mi código HTML es el siguiente:

```js
let fecha=""
function cargarFecha(){
    fecha=document.querySelector("#txtFecha").value
    fecha=fecha.replace("-","")
    fecha=fecha.replace("-","")
}

let fechaDeHoy=mostrarFechaHoy()

function mostrarFechaHoy(){
    let fecha= new Date()
    let anio=fecha.getFullYear()
    let mes=fecha.getMonth()+1
    if (mes<10) mes=`0${mes}`
    let dia=fecha.getDate()
    let mifecha=`${anio}${mes}${dia}`
    return mifecha 
}

function crearViaje(){
    let unBuque = document.querySelector("#txtNombreBuque").value;
    let unaCant = Number(document.querySelector("#txtMaxCont").value);
    let unaFecha = document.querySelector("#txtFecha").value;
    let cupoDisp = unaCant
    
    if(validarCamposViaje(unBuque, unaCant, unaFecha)){
        if(fecha>=fechaDeHoy){
            agregarViaje(unBuque, unaCant ,unaFecha, cupoDisp); 
            document.querySelector("#msjCrearViaje").innerHTML = "El viaje se creo exitosamente";
        }else{
            document.querySelector("#msjCrearViaje").innerHTML = "La fecha ingresada no puede ser menor a la fecha del dia de hoy";
        }
    }else{
        document.querySelector("#msjCrearViaje").innerHTML = "No puede haber campos vacios";
    }
}



class Viaje{
    constructor (unNombreBuque, unaCantMaxima, unaFechaLlegada, unaLineaCarga, unCupoDisponible){

        this.id=contadorDeViajes 
        this.nombreBuque=unNombreBuque
        this.cantMaxima=unaCantMaxima
        this.fechaLlegada=unaFechaLlegada
        this.idLineaCarga = unaLineaCarga
        this.cupoDisponible = unCupoDisponible
        contadorDeViajes++
    }
}


function validarCamposViaje(buque, cantMax, fecha){
    return buque !="" && cantMax !="" && fecha !="";
}

listaViajes = [];

function agregarViaje(unNombreBuque, unaCantMaxima, unaFechaLlegada){
    let unViaje = new Viaje(unNombreBuque, unaCantMaxima, unaFechaLlegada, usuarioLogueado, unCupoDisponible)
    listaViajes.push(unViaje)
}
```

```html
<div id="crearViaje">
  <h3>Creacion de viaje</h3>
  <label for="txtNombreBuque">Ingrese nombre del buque:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtNombreBuque"><br>
  <label for="txtMaxCont">Ingrese catidad maxima de contenedores</label>
  <input type="number" id="txtMaxCont"><br>
  <label for="txtFecha">Ingrese fecha de llegada del buque</label>
  <input type="date" id="txtFecha"><br>
  <input type="button" id="btnCrearViaje" value="Crear">
  <p id="msjCrearViaje"></p>
</div>
```

Cuando presiono el botón crear viaje con un fecha como por ejemplo (12/01/2023) el mensaje que sale en el párrafo es "La fecha ingresada no puede ser menor a la fecha del día de hoy"

Comment: Hola, te hago una consulta, porque no veo donde definis la fecha de hoy, y por otro lado, el valor de la fecha ingresada lo guardas en "unaFecha", y en el if pones "fecha".
Puede que estes definiendo mal las variables a comparar?

Comment: ademas de lo que dice @Carlos al instanciar un viaje con new Viaje() pasas al contructor una variable (usuarioLogeado) que no esta en el constructor de la clase

Comment: Si pido disculpas mi codigo no estaba completo. ahora si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 tiene validaciones básicas para los formularios, que podrías ocupar de esta manera, con lo cual tú código de reduce drásticamente

```js
const listaViajes = [];
class Viaje{
    constructor(id,nombre, cantidad, fecha){
        this.id=id;
        this.nombre=nombre
        this.cantidad=cantidad
        this.fecha=fecha;
    }
}

function Guardar(){
event.preventDefault(); 
  listaViajes.push(
  new Viaje(
     listaViajes.length,
     txtNombreBuque.value,
     txtMaxCont.value, 
     txtFecha.value
  ));
  
  console.log(listaViajes);
}
```

```html
<form id="crearViaje" onsubmit="Guardar()">
  <h3>Creacion de viaje</h3>
  <label for="txtNombreBuque">Ingrese nombre del buque:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtNombreBuque" title="Ingrese nombre del buque" required><br>
  <label for="txtMaxCont">Ingrese catidad maxima de contenedores</label>
  <input type="number" id="txtMaxCont" min="1" value="1" required><br>
  <label for="txtFecha">Ingrese fecha de llegada del buque</label>
  <input type="date" id="txtFecha" onfocus="this.min=new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)" required><br>
  <button type="submit" id="btnCrearViaje">Crear</button>
  <p id="msjCrearViaje"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código lo simplifique usando las propiedades de Viaje que de verdad si estas usando porque había algunas que no tenían sentido y no sabía para que servían, además no tienen inputs propios y no quieres validarlas al parecer. en la funcion `validarCamposViaje()` tambien valido la fecha. El HTML no lo cambie en nada. Entonces:

```
class Viaje{
    static contadorDeViajes = 0; // si quiero un contador general uso una variable estatica(con static es una variable perteneciente a la clase, no a la instancia), la inicializamos en 1
    constructor (unNombreBuque, unaCantMaxima, unaFechaLlegada){
        this.nombreBuque=unNombreBuque
        this.cantMaxima=unaCantMaxima
        this.fechaLlegada=unaFechaLlegada
        Viaje.contadorDeViajes++; // como la variable es de la clase tengo que poner Viaje.contador y no this.contador
    }
}

const listaViajes = [];

function crearViaje(){
  let unBuque = document.querySelector("#txtNombreBuque").value;
  let unaCant = Number(document.querySelector("#txtMaxCont").value);
  let unaFecha = document.querySelector("#txtFecha").value;
  let checkvalue = validarCamposViaje(unBuque, unaCant, unaFecha) // guardo el resultado de la funcion
  if (checkvalue===true){ // si pasa las validaciones
    agregarViaje(unBuque, unaCant, unaFecha); // se crea el viaje
    console.log("viaje agregado correctamente");
    console.log(listaViajes); // imprimo lista y compruebo
    console.log(`contador de viajes: ${Viaje.contadorDeViajes}`); // compruebo el contador
  } else {  // si no pasa las validaciones
    console.log(`error al agregar viaje: ${checkvalue}`); // imprimo el string devuelto por la funcion
  }
}

function validarCamposViaje(buque, cantMax, fecha){
  let splitted = fecha.split("-"); // divido el string fecha en un array con año mes y dia en cada posicion
  let date = new Date([...splitted]) // uso el array para crear un Date() usando el contructor Date(Year,Month,Day). Aca uso el operador args. 
  let actualDate = new Date(); // creo fecha actual
  if(buque === "")  return "el nombre del buque no puede estar vacio" 
  if(cantMax < 1) return "la cantidad no puede ser 0 o menos"
  if(date.getTime()<actualDate.getTime()) return "la fecha no puede ser anterior a la actual" 
  // "El método getTime() devuelve el valor numérico correspondiente a la hora para la fecha especificada según la hora universal"
  // entonces como devuelve un numerico las podemos comparar directamente con < o >
  return true // si no pasa por uno de los ifs entonces devuelve true (los datos son correctos)
}

function agregarViaje(unNombreBuque, unaCantMaxima, unaFechaLlegada){
    let unViaje = new Viaje(unNombreBuque, unaCantMaxima, unaFechaLlegada)
    listaViajes.push(unViaje)
}

document.getElementById("btnCrearViaje").addEventListener("click", () => { // agrego el evento al boton de crear 
  crearViaje(); // entonces se ejecutan las funciones
})
```

Espero haberme dado a entender bien, cualquier duda que tengas solo pregunta.